# Finding the length of sscanf() without storing the result

Tags: c, scanf

How would I go about finding the length of a `sscanf()` where I am scanning from a string up until a certain character WITHOUT actually storing it?

```
sscanf(stringToBeTested, "%[upUntilThis]", StoreToThisString)
strlen(sscanf(stringToBeTested, "%[upUntilThis]", StoreToThisString))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can suppress the assignment in a conversion specification with a `*`, as in:

```
int index_at_end = -1;
sscanf(stringToBeTested, "%*[^upUntilThis]%n", &index_at_end);
```

The `%n` tells you the number of bytes scanned up to that point in the processing. Note that the `%n` operation is not counted, so `sscanf()` will return 0 successful conversions.  That may make life too tricky.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for [`strchr(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strchr/):

```
int length = strchr(stringToBeTested, upUntilThis) - stringToBeTested;
```

Comment: The answer ignores `StoreToThisString`.  Of course, it's not Carl's fault; the question requires a very vivid imagination...  @user2778481, can you read your questions before you press the button to ask them?

Comment: Didn't OP want to *not store* the string?

Comment: yeah i wanted to not store the string, i just wanted to find out the length